# How to detect the "closed_by_user" event via the new "Google 3P Authorization JavaScript Library API"

Tags: javascript, events, google-oauth

I'm currently using the [Google Sign-In JavaScript Platform Library for web](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference).
Via the `grantOfflineAccess()` function I request access to scopes from the users Google account with `ux_mode: 'popup'`.

```js
auth2.grantOfflineAccess().then(
  response => {
    // response handling 
  },
  error => {
    // error handling
  },
)
```

Currently I'm able to detect if the popup is closed without authorization, because the error callback is called with this data:

```js
{
  error: "popup_closed_by_user"
}
```

As Google is discontinuing this Sign-In API I'm migrating to the new [Google 3P Authorization JavaScript Library](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/reference/js-reference)

As part of the migration, I have modified the authorization flow to code like this:

```js
google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient({
  client_id: '[...].apps.googleusercontent.com',
  fetch_basic_profile: false,
  ux_mode: 'popup',
  scope: '[...]',
  callback: response => {
    // handle google feedback
  },
}).requestCode()
```

[As the docs state](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/reference/js-reference#CodeResponse), the callback can have the parameters `code`, `scope`, `state`, `error`, `error_description`, `error_uri` and I expected it to be the equivalent of the previous callbacks, but it does not seem to be called for the `popup_closed_by_user` event.

Unfortunately, I was also not able to find an alternative callback.

Is someone aware wether the `popup_closed_by_user` event can be detected with the new library?

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same issue and try to find a workaround but nothing yet. Maybe I should try to contact a support from google.

Comment: This is by design, but might need to change. Could you describe what your app will display to the user when they cancel ?   The user will be aware already what the situation is as they've terminated the process. It would be helpful to better understand what you'll want to do differently if a popup_closed_by_user event is returned.

Comment: @bdid Currently, I’m switching the auth button label from “Sign in with Google” to “Waiting for auth” (and display a small loader) while the popup is open to indicate the required interaction with the popup. I think it makes the site more responsive and might help users who mistake the popup as advertisement or similar. 

As a temp. workaround I’m “simulating” the event by detecting that the tab regains focus.. but it doesn’t certainly mean, that the popup was actually closed, just that is was temp. dismissed. 
An event to the registered callback function would be great!

Comment: I'm in a similar situation as @zZeepo, while the popup is shown, I'm displaying a spinning wheel as long the authrisation is not done. As I currently cannot detect when the popup is closed, when a user close the popup, my spinning wheel is still displaying itself. This is not the expected behavior of my application ^^'

Comment: Also in my case, I handle the request of token through a js promise: https://github.com/frozar/gdrive-tree/blob/d04ea49333a980bba1e86e41cec0aaaa8a48bcc0/src/main/triggerFilesRequest.js#L84
If the user closes the popup, this promise never comes back and cannot be handled properly.

Comment: @RozarFabien adding a timeout to the promise would be good here, even without the issue of user cancellation events  that we are discussing other problems like network timeouts should be handled gracefully and won't be addressed by a close event being returned.

Comment: Stay tuned, there should be an update on response types for callbacks in the coming weeks.

Comment: @bdid Thank you for the advice about the timeout. And great news regarding potential updates on response types for callbacks :)

Comment: @bdid, Is this in IssueTracker so that we can follow the progress of this update?

Answer (score 0):

Non-OAuth errors can now be handled in the [`error_callback`](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/error#non-oauth_errors) callback when the popup UX mode is used.

To handle the popup closed error in this case:

```js
google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient({
  client_id: '[...].apps.googleusercontent.com',
  fetch_basic_profile: false,
  ux_mode: 'popup',
  scope: '[...]',
  callback: response => {
    // handle authorization response
  },
  error_callback: err => {
    if (err.type === 'popup_closed') {
      // handle closed popup
    }
    // other errors
  },
}).requestCode()
```